# Database of predominant religion by country?

Tags: data-request

Is there such a database?

This can be inferred from UNData census data, however, each country has a different set of options, e.g., some countries differentiate between different Christian churches, while others don't.

Comment: For some reason, the comment about differentiation of regligions reminded me of an Emo Philips joke : http://www.theguardian.com/stage/2005/sep/29/comedy.religion

Answer (score 5):

The Factbook includes a religon entry, for example, the entry for Canada reads:

Roman Catholic 42.6%, Protestant 23.3% (United Church 9.5%, Anglican 6.8%, Baptist 2.4%, Lutheran 2%), other Christian 4.4%, Muslim 1.9%, other and unspecified 11.8%, none 16% (2001 census)

You can get all the data in the public domain in JSON from [`openmundi/factbook.json`](https://github.com/openmundi/factbook.json) for example. Canada example in JSON:

`"religions": {
      "text": "Roman Catholic 42.6%, Protestant 23.3% (United Church 9.5%, Anglican 6.8%, Baptist 2.4%, Lutheran 2%), other Christian 4.4%, Muslim 1.9%, other and unspecified 11.8%, none 16% (2001 census)"
    }`